# get all variables in bash and convert to a url query string

Tags: php, bash, shell

I need to get all the variables set in a bash script and turn it into a query string.  What I need to do is pass all the variables that have been created in the bash script to a php file.  The variable are some times set and sometimes not as well as the amount of them is a lot of them.

```
#!/bin/bash

id=19
url="http://domain.com"
#this var should be generated 
query='id=19&url=http://domain.com'
php /srv/install-post.php -- $query
```

Comment: I don't think there's any automatic way to to this. There are commands to list all variables, but they'll include environment variables inherited from the parent process, as well as lots of predefined variables. There's no way to get just the ones set in the script.

Comment: so if I was to have the variables that are generated then a prefix like `bs_id` and `bs_url` then what your saying is I could get all the environmental vars and then could just pull the ones with the prefix maybe?  to when I could phrase it to the query string maybe?

Comment: Yes, you could use `set | grep '^bs_'`

Comment: Encoding them properly will be a PITA in bash -- it doesn't have anything like PHP's `urlencode()` function.

Comment: so using `set` wouldn't that just make an object hash or something of the vars?  if so then I could just do a loop and concatenate it to a string in a url query format?

Comment: `set` just prints them out. You'll need to feed that to a loop that builds the query string you want.

Comment: well that is what I was asking about lol.. I'm not a super user on this yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query=
for var in ${!bs_*}; do
    if [ -n "$query" ];
    then query="$query&"
    fi
    query="$query${var#bs_}=${!var}"
done
```

`${!bs_*}` expands to the list of all variables that begin with `bs_`.

`${var#bs}` expands to the value of `$var` with the `bs_` prefix removed.

`${!var}` is variable indirection -- `$var` is taken to be the name of a variable, and this gets the value of the variable with that name.

You can find all these constructs in the **Parameter expansion** section of the `bash` man page.

Note that this makes no attempt to deal with special characters in the values that require percent-encoding in URLs.

Comment: Fixed it -- There's no `$` in `${!var}`.

Comment: well now that I think about it the url encoding may not be needed since I'm passing it in as to a php script.  so making it as the answer..